# Properly discontinuous group action

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> Let $\mathrm{a}:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathrm{C}$ and $\mathrm{b}: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathrm{C}$ be the homeomorphisms of the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ defined by
> $$\mathrm{a}\mathrm{z}=\mathrm{z}+i$$
> $$\mathrm{b}\mathrm{z}=\overline{\mathrm{z}}+\frac{1}{2}+i$$
> show that $\mathrm{b}\mathrm{a}=\mathrm{a}^{-1}\mathrm{b}$ and deduce that
> $$\mathrm{G}=\left\{\mathrm{a}^m\mathrm{b}^{2n}\mathrm{b}^\epsilon :m,n\in\mathbb{Z},\epsilon\in 0\space \text{or} \space1\right\}$$
> is a  group of homeomorphisms of $\mathrm{C}$.Furthermore, prove that the action of $\mathrm{G}$ is properly discontinuous and that the orbit space $\mathrm{C}/\mathrm{G}$ is Hausdorff.

The first part $ba=a^{-1}b$ is easy to prove, but the best way to prove that G is a subgroup is with the fact that for every $x,y \in G$ $xy^{-1} \in G$?

Because I get
$$a^mb^{2n}b^e(a^pb^{2q}b^r)^{-1}=a^mb^{2n}b^e b^{-r}b^{-2q}a^{-p}$$

But I'm stuck in how to use $ba=a^{-1}b$

And for the rest I'm not sure, I know that $b$ acts on $z$ flipping around the real line and adding $\frac{1}{2}$ and $a^m$ map $z$ $m$ units "higher", but formally I don't know how to do it...

Comment: Not my area, but I'm just curious: why did the book use $b^{2n}b^\epsilon$, where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $\epsilon \in \{0, 1\}$? Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't that just $b^n$ where $n \in \Bbb{Z}$? It seems like a torturous way of saying the same thing (like saying "even or odd powers of $b$" instead of saying "integer powers of $b$").

Comment: The set $G = \{ \dots \}$ is a set of words that are a power of $a$ followed by a (strangely written) power of $b$.  The word you have, $a^mb^{2n} \cdots a^{-p}$ is almost already a power of $a$ followed by a power of $b$.  All you need to do is use the relation you have to migrate the product of $a$s in $a^{-p}$ ahead of all the $b$s.  The very first step is $$b^{-2q}a^{-p} = b^{-2q+1}b^{-1}a^{-1}a^{-p+1} = b^{-2q+1}a^{\text{something}}b^{\text{something}}a^{-p+1}\text{.}   $$  It might help to prove an induction or two so you can move all of $a^{-p}$ at once past powers of $b$.

Comment: You can rewrite $G = \{ a^n b^m : m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. You first want to show it's closed under composition. You have $a^n b^m a^r b^s.$ By your assumption you can write $ba = a^{-1} b$, so write $b^m a^r = b^{m-1} b a^r = b^{m-1} a^{-1} b a^{r-1}$ (assuming things are positive, otherwise adjust signs). Keep repeating until you get $b^{m-1} a^{-r} b$. Iterate and you'll get $a^{(-1)^m r} b^m$, so $a^n b^m a^r b^s = a^{n+(-1)^m r} b^{m+s}.$ Inverses should be same kind of trick.

Comment: For properly discontinuous you can pretend your neighborhoods are boxes and just take a box whose height and width are smaller than $1/4$. Then $a$ moves it up $1$ so $a(U)$ can't intersect $U$ and $b$ flips it over the $x$-axis, moves it up $1$ and to the right by $1/2$. Since your box is small enough this can't overlap.